# What is the best equipment set?

Tags: crisis-core-final-fantasy-7

I know that all the pieces of the Genji armour set are good but are there any better pieces of equipment that I can obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I played but I recall these two:-

Divine Slayer (beat Minerva), which will:

- increase your HP, MP, and AP by +100%
- increase all your stats +50
- break the HP, MP, AP limits
- gives Auto-Libra.

Also, Heike Soul (finish all missions I believe) which does the following:

- Break HP, MP, AP, and Damage Limit
- Add Sudden Death, Poison, Silence, Stop and Stun to 'Fight' command
  (and adds them to some other physical techniques as well)
- Absorbs All Elements
- Auto-Potion
- Increases Drop Rates for enemies
- 100% successful steal
- Stolen and Dropped items are 100% rare
- Doubles Gil, Item/Materia from enemies
- Smart Consumer Level 1 (increases item effects)
- Double Magic
- Auto-Libra
- SP Master Level 1 (spend SP to increase damage done and reduce damage taken)

Comment: but where can I obtain these items,I already got max Helth

Comment: I have where in the brackets, you must beat Minerva in a mission for Divine Slayer and then finish all missions for Heike Soul.